Docker minio web console access not accessible
i have used host windows virtual box and running rocky linux and docker.
highly appreciated results/inputs

docker minio pulled
docker run executed
virtual box port forward enabled 9000 , 9001
results displayed below
web access from host pc - not found
http://127.0.0.1:9001/

docker pull minio/minio:latest
docker run \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin" \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123" \
  -e "MINIO_VOLUMES=/mnt/data" \
  -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 \
  -v ./miniodata:/mnt/data \
  --name minio --hostname minio \
  minio/minio:latest server /data --console-address ":9001"
  
  [admin@rlinux92 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                           NAMES
da5ccc1c6230   minio/minio:latest   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:9000-9001->9000-9001/tcp, :::9000-9001->9000-9001/tcp   minio
[admin@rlinux92 ~]$


This commend will works
docker run -d \
  --name minio-service \
  -p 9000:9000 \
  -p 9001:9001 \
  -e MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin \
  -e MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123 \
  -v ./miniodata:/mnt/data \
  --restart always \
  --name minio --hostname minio \
  minio/minio:latest \
  server --address ":9001" --console-address ":9000" /data


server --address ":9001" --console-address ":9000" /data: Command to start the MinIO server with the specified settings.
Access UI
http://127.0.0.1:9000/




Thanks Sir, I found from minio website that out of host machine where docker runs wont be able to access[my case: VM : linux host], later i did add port forward from vm network settings 0.0.0.0:91 to 10.0.2.15 : 9001(linux), so that its able to access it from windows host with port 91
